# Vim: good pascal support (syntax, indent, probably omnicomplete)

Tags: vim, freepascal

I need to work on existing freepascal project ( it's an open-source project [double commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/) ), so I'm trying to set Vim for editing source files, but pascal support bundled with Vim is surprisingly ugly.

More, I can't even find anything for better pascal support. At least, I really need for working syntax and indent scripts (both of them are buggy by default).

It would be very nice to set up omnicompletion too, but it seems this is completely hopeless.

I will probably hack on syntax and indent scripts myself, but I can't believe we still don't have them, so I decided to ask first.

Comment: If Google didn't find it it probably doesn't exist but I'm sure your contribution will be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can improve the situation by telling Vim to use the "delphi" mode instead of the "pascal" mode (this trick works with Emacs too). The reason for this is that in general "Pascal" refers to the old language designed by Wirth in the '70, while Free Pascal incorporates many syntactical additions introduced by Turbo Pascal and Delphi in the following years. Most of the development on Vim/Emacs modes usually goes in the Delphi mode, not the Pascal one.

Have a look at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3078. This will not provide autocompletion, but at least it will highlight keywords like "unit", "interface", "implementation", etc., as well as // comments, correctly.

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up with this script, but I forgot to mention that here. It isn't so good, but since we really seem to not have anything better, I'd accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As VIM 7.4.52 for Linux there isn't 'Delphi' option. So far, the 'Pascal' mode works good.

Comment: Its not the syntax mode, but an option for the syntax highlight file. On my vimrc I have the following options: `let g:pascal_delphi=true` and `let g:pascal_fpc=true`. Works with the default pascal mode.

Answer (score 0):

for a freepascal project (fpc), you need to get `fpc.vim`.

### Doing it with 'Plug'

open your .vimrc file and add:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'vim-scripts/fpc.vim'

call plug#end()
```

reopen your vim, and use the command `:PlugInstall`

### Highlighting

in order to highlight pascal use command:

```
:set filetype=pascal
```

this also enables indent for the code. and it will auto indent the existing code.

or you can use:

```
:set syntax=pascal
```

this may fail to indent.